# My spring boot app doesn't connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mysql-connector

I'm trying to connect my spring boot application to MySql but it isn't working.

EmployeeManager.java file

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class EmployeemanagerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmployeemanagerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Employee.java file

```java
package com.example.demo.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String jobTitle;
    private String phone;
    private String imageUrl;
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String empCode;
    
    
    public Employee(String name, String email, String jobTitle, String phone, String imageUrl,
            String empCode) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.empCode = empCode;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getJobTitle() {
        return jobTitle;
    }
    public void setJobTitle(String jobTitle) {
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }
    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
    public String getEmpCode() {
        return empCode;
    }
    public void setEmpCode(String empCode) {
        this.empCode = empCode;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email + ", jobTitle=" + jobTitle + ", phone="
                + phone + ", imageUrl=" + imageUrl + ", empCode=" + empCode + "]";
    }
    
}
```

application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employeemanager
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=pass   
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>employeemanager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>employeemanager</name>
    <description>employee manager app</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

It shows the following errors when I run it:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution

Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
```

I've also created the database employeemanager.

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| hello              |
| db1                |
| employeemanager    |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is literally the first project I'm doing in spring boot connecting to mySQL database so I really can't understand where the problem is.

Comment: Do not exclude the autoconfig. The properties look good. Do you have a dependency to the database driver in your pom.xml (or gradle)? The entity class is not correct but it should not cause the datasource initialization error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Mar-Z I've added mySql driver dependency

Comment: Now you can connect but the user has no access granted. This is a known issue when using root user over JDBC. Please create a different user for your application and grant him the needed access to your database. As described here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/